# Convertir múltiples variables character a integer R

Tags: r

Tengo un df con 25 columnas, de las cuales 18 son de tipo character pero con valor numérico, y los valores "NULL" también son character por lo tanto no lo reconoce como NA. Como podría cambiar los valores "NULL" a "0" o simplemente transformar las columnas a integer y que los "NULL" se queden como NA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si imaginamos un `data.frame` como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("1", "2", "3", "NULL", "4.5"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                        ncol=5))
df

    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1    2  4.5 NULL  4.5  4.5
2 NULL    1    2    3    2
3 NULL NULL    3    2    3
4    3    3 NULL NULL NULL
```

Puedes aplicar `as.integer()` por columna:

```
apply(df, 2, as.integer)

     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  2  4 NA  4  4
[2,] NA  1  2  3  2
[3,] NA NA  3  2  3
[4,]  3  3 NA NA NA
```

Ten en cuenta, que el retorno es una matriz, pero es trivial convertirla a un `data.frame` y particularmente, nota que valores con decimales como `4.5` se truncan, cualquier otro valor que no pueda convertirse será un `NA`